# Oracle DB, validate xml during insert

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-xml-db

I'm trying to validate a document XML during it's inserting into a table in ORACLE database. I've define a XML Schema and a XMLTYPE with this schema in my table but the db allow me to insert a wrong xml.

My schema:

```
BEGIN
dbms_xmlschema.registerschema(
  schemaurl => 'http://www.testXml.com/schema.xsd',
  schemadoc => xmltype('<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:complexType name="Name_tp">
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
      <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Category_tp">
  <xs:attribute name="NumPrize" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
  <xs:attribute name="From" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:attribute name="To" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
  <xs:attribute name="Type" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="Age" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Match_tp">
  <xs:attribute name="typeMatch" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="GolfCompetition_tp">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Name" type="Name_tp"/>
    <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:date"/>
    <xs:element name="Sponsor" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="Category" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="Category_tp"/>
    <xs:element name="Reserved" type="Match_tp" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="GolfCompetition" type="GolfCompetition_tp"/>
</xs:schema>'),
local => true,
gentypes => false,
gentables => false
);
END;
```

My db schema:

```
CREATE TYPE t_gara AS OBJECT (
  id INTEGER,
  informazioni XMLTYPE
);

CREATE TABLE gara OF t_gara () XMLType COLUMN informazioni
XMLSCHEMA "http://www.testXml.com/schema.xsd"
ELEMENT "GolfCompetition";
```

When i try to insert this row i've not problem:

```
INSERT INTO GARA VALUES(1, XMLType('<GolfCompetition>
<Name Id="324">Coppa del Presidente</Name>
<Date>2009-12-25</Date>
<Sponsor>Lavazza S.p.A</Sponsor>
<Category NumPrize="3" From="0" To="12" Type="First"/>
<Category NumPrize="3" From="13" To="24" Type="Second"/>
<Category NumPrize="2" From="25" To="36" Type="Third"/>
<Category NumPrize="1" Type="Lady"/>
<Category NumPrize="1" Type="Over" Age="40"/>
</GolfCompetition>'));
```

But this works to:

```
INSERT INTO GARA VALUES(2, XMLType('<GolfCompetition>
<Category NumPrize="3" From="0" To="12" Type="First"/>
<Category NumPrize="3" From="13" To="24" Type="Second"/>
<Category NumPrize="2" From="25" To="36" Type="Third"/>
<Category NumPrize="1" Type="Lady"/>
<Category NumPrize="1" Type="Over" Age="40"/>
</GolfCompetition>'));
```

How can I solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatic schema validation requires storing the XML in a binary format, not object-relationally.

From the [XML Developer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb08tra.htm#ADXDB0900):

> For XMLType data that is stored object-relationally, full validation
>   requires building a DOM, which can be costly in terms of memory
>   management. For this reason, Oracle XML DB does not automatically
>   perform full validation when you insert or update data that is stored
>   object-relationally.

Re-register the schema, adding this parameter:

```
...
options => dbms_xmlschema.REGISTER_BINARYXML
...
```

Create the table like this:

```
create table gara
(
    id number,
    informazioni xmltype
) xmltype informazioni
    store as binary xml
    XMLSCHEMA "http://www.testXml.com/schema.xsd"
    ELEMENT "GolfCompetition";
```

Now the first insert will work but the second will fail with this error:

```
ORA-64464: XML event error
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LSX-00213: only 0 occurrences of particle "Name", minimum is 1
```